# Spring Expression for File writeString gives AccessDeniedException

Tags: spring-integration, spring-el

```
inbound:
  processed:
    path: C://inbound/processed/FedEx.txt

   @Bean(name = "inboundProcessedDirectory")
        public File inboundProcessedDirectory(@Value("${inbound.processed.path}") String path) {
            return makeDir(path);
        }
    
    private File makeDir(String path) {
            File file = new File(path);
            file.mkdirs();
            return file;
        }
    
    
    Expression parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    parser.parseExpression("T(java.nio.file.Files).writeString(T(java.nio.file.Path).of(@inboundProcessedDirectory.path), payload)");
```

Error: AccessDeniedException: C:\inbound\processed\FedEx.txt

Is there a way to give a proper path for Spel?

Comment: Please, share more stack trace about that error. It is not clear why you judge that the path is wrong, but not something else. See that `AccessDeniedException` JavaDocs. Also: this looks cleaner: `"T(java.nio.file.Files).writeString(@inboundProcessedDirectory.toPath(), payload)"`. And one more: why you don't use a `FileWritingMessageHandler` from the framework: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/file.html#file-writing ? Are you sure that you use Spring Integration: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration to point via its tag over here...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Am using spring Integration SFTP 5.5.13. While debugging manually changed the value(replaced the black slash() with forward-slash(/)), the file is written successfully. Is there a way SpEl can interpret the file path correctly?

Comment: Good to know you have found the problem and some solution. Feel free to form it as an answer to your own question. Not sure why you think that SpEL has do something for you since it is just an expression language on top of plain Java...